# Accordion data is not updating in angular application

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion components in my angular application. I am unable to bind the updated data to the accordion component.
Please find the example in below stackblitz link

[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-ejs-repo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the above code if I click the change button data should be updated but empty data is showing in accordion.
Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use track by to Understand angular that data is changed.

```
*ngFor = "let item of data1;trackBy:identify"

identify(index,item){
  return this.count;
 }
```

[whatch this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-ejs-repo-6nmwfv)

Answer (score 1):

Actually i don't like the method mentioned in the documents and i think it is for adding items to existing accordion not for re-rendering it entirely as your sample.

Since you have `*ngIf` directive to show it conditionally. We can trick angular to re-render it like below :

```
 this.data1.length = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.data1 = this.count % 2 == 0 ? [...this.items] : [...this.items1];   
    });
```

See Stackblitz [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-ejs-repo-s8kzes).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/accordion/how-to/load-accordion-items-dynamically), it appears that you need to use the public method `addItem()` available in the `AccordionComponent` that you can retrieve thanks to your `@ViewChild`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: addItem() will add new item but we can not reload the full datasource.